# In Linux, how is a program loaded into memory when the OS decided to run it?

Tags: cache, process, linux-kernel

As we know, Linux implements page cache to store the code or data from pieces of a file that will be potentially used. One of my question is, when a program, e.g. vim, is going to run, its data and code will be firstly loaded into those page cache, right?

And I am not sure about my another understanding, either. Whether does the OS just load some pieces of the code that will be use immediately when the program starts? Or OS load them all at once? The OS use the pace cache of files to store the loaded codes and data, right? What kind of function of module does OS use to perform the code loading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> its data and code will be firstly loaded into those page cache, right?

Yes.

> Whether does the OS just load some pieces of the code that will be use
>   immediately when the program starts? Or OS load them all at once?

Some pieces. Actually when code actually will be executed - page_fault will occur, and page will be moved to memory (page_cache) from associated file

> What kind of function of module does OS use to perform the code
>   loading?

load_elf_binary
http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/binfmt_elf.c#L663